# How to find the number of Total Users in Blaze meter report? It is showing max users but not displayed the total users

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

[image]

1. There are 600 users in the JMeter script but it's showing only the 385 Max users and I'm running the script through "Taurus"

   Command: `bzt 600users.jmx -report`.
2. Even I'm not able to see the log Tab in the Blaze meter to check the Total Users. How can I check Total Users are executed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your test duration is 30 seconds so you need to ensure that:

1. All 600 users will have a chance to start during this period, i.e. your [ramp-up period](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) should be lower than 30 seconds
2. Each of 600 users should have sufficient number of loops (iterations) otherwise you can run into the situation when some threads have already finished their job and were shut down and some haven't been yet started. See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) for more comprehensive explanation

Comment: But when I'm Running for the second or Third time its giving the  Actual Max Users. How can I check the How many users are executed?